# How to make a drop-down list in the view containing items from the database?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core

In one of my views, created specifically for a `Create` method, I need to show the `Name` of certain things in a dropdown list, and, once selected, pass their `Id` to the controller.

Using my code I got pretty close - however, I don't feel like this is actually the way it should be done. I kindly ask you to provide me advice on what could work better, any tips and hints are highly welcomed!

**DependencyController.cs**

```
public IActionResult Create()
    {
        List<Release> releaseList = new List<Release>();
        List<Phase> phaseList = new List<Phase>();
        List<TaskModel> taskList = new List<TaskModel>();

        string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string sql = "ReadReleases";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            using (SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    Release release = new Release();
                    release.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Id"]);
                    release.Name = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Name"]);
                    releaseList.Add(release);
                }
            }

            ViewBag.Releases = releaseList;
```

This is a small snippet of the `Create` method from the controller. Basically, I connect to the database, `Select * FROM Releases` through the stored procedure and fill in the list which is eventually stored in a ViewBag.

**Create.cshtml**

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ReleaseName"></label>
            <select asp-items="@new SelectList(ViewBag.Releases)" asp-for="ReleaseName"></select>
        </div>
```

Above is the code from the view. I think it's an issue there as my lists look something like this:

[image]

Their number is alright, but what am I missing? Why isn't their name shown?

Therefore:

1. What should be fixed in order to get my lists show the correct name instead of the `Intersection.Models.Release`?
2. What else should be added to get the `Id` instead of the `Name` as a value when passing the selected item to the controller?

EDIT:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sql = "CreateDependency";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@ReleaseId",
                    Value = dependency.ReleaseId,
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                    Size = 50
                };
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

Comment: Does overriding of `ToString()` method in `Release` class will help you?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, you mean in the `Release` model class? I am not quite sure what you mean by the `ToString()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gauravsa's answer is right and this is another way of doing that.

```
<select asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Releases, "Id", "Name"))" asp-for="Id"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks! However, afterward, how can I pass the value to the controller? I edited the original post to include the `POST` Create method. Right now, `Value = dependency.ReleaseId,` is supposed to get the inserted value. How can I pass the selected item to this value?

Comment: You are passing a "@model" in your .cshtml, and that model has the ```asp-for="Id"``` field.So your "Model" will transfer your value to your controller.

Comment: nevermind the last one, I got it fixed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can change your controller side code:

```
ViewBag.Releases = new SelectList(releaseList, "Id", "Name");
```

On the client side, you can use:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Releases, null, new { @class ="form-control" })
```

Comment: Thanks! However, afterward, how can I pass the value to the controller? I edited the original post to include the `POST` Create method. Right now, `Value = dependency.ReleaseId,` is supposed to get the inserted value. How can I pass the selected item to this value?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily acquire this by using general drop-down

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.DropDownList("Id",new SelectList(@ViewBag.Releases,"Id","Name"),"Select")
</div>
```